# Error installing ionic cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, hybrid-mobile-app

```
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:172390
npm ERR! version":"3.20.2","dependencies":
{"basic-auth":"1.0.0","connect":"2.2 

npm ERR!                                                                      

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Inspiron 15\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-
01T08_02_19_789Z-debug.log
```

I'm keep getting this error while trying to install cordova ionic. I've already installed node js latest version to my computer.

Comment: add the log output

Comment: try running this command npm cache clean --force

Comment: It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
```

And then :

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: I think she is on windows as you can see at her error log path…so linux command will not be the solution here :-)

Comment: You're right ^^. I let this here though if some Linux users  face the same problem :)